# Which size class do I use for Portrait/PortraitUpsideDown app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, size-classes

So i'm making a universal devices app but not sure which size classes to use for iPhone and iPad but i'm making the app Portrait and PortraitUpsideDown only.

Do I use 2 size classes one for iPhones and another for iPad or do I use 1 size class for iPhone and iPad?

What size classes do I use if I want iPhone and iPad in Portrait and PortraitUpsideDown?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use different size classes for different layout .According to apple it has 4 type

1. for iPad (landscape and portrait mode)-regular height and regular width
2. for iPhone (portrait) - compact width and regular height
3. for iPhone in landscape(except iphone6 plus and iPhone 7 plus)- compact height and compact width
4. for iphone6 plus and iPhone 7 plus (landscape mode) - regular width and compact height

---> you are using only portrait mode so you can use

Regular height , regular width for iPad portrait

Regular height , compact width for iPhone portrait

for more information
https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/size-classes-ipad-portrait-landscape-55f59173c65a

Answer (score 0):

Portrait and portrait upside down are the same in terms of size classes.  Compact width and regular height is for all iPhones in portrait and regular width/regular height is for all iPads in either orientatation